# how i can do start date and end date validation in the angular by using ngModule event

Tags: angular, validation, angular-validation

in this example I am. trying to validate the start date and end date but I am facing an error in it can someone suggest me right direction. please help me with a start date and end date validation.
this is the HTML file I use in this.

```
                <div class="my-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="Test_BidProgramStartDate">
                        {{ l('BidProgramStartDate') }} *
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="date"
                        #Test_BidProgramStartDate="ngModel"
                        id="Test_BidProgramStartDate"
                        class="form-control"
                        [(ngModel)]="test.bidProgramStartDate"
                        name="BidProgramStartDate"
                        required
                        (change)="chngDt($event)"
                    />
                    <validation-messages [formCtrl]="Test_BidProgramStartDate"></validation-messages>
                </div>

                <div class="my-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="Test_BidProgrammeEndDate">
                        {{ l('BidProgrammeEndDate') }} *
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="date"
                        #Test_BidProgrammeEndDate="ngModel"
                        id="Test_BidProgrammeEndDate"
                        class="form-control"
                        [(ngModel)]="test.bidProgrammeEndDate"
                        name="BidProgrammeEndDate"
                        required
                        (change)="chngDt($event)"



                    />
```

date must be greater than start date

```js
    chngDt(event: any) {
console.log('chngDt', event, this.test.bidProgramStartDate, this.test.bidProgrammeEndDate)
if( this.test.bidProgramStartDate > this.test.bidProgrammeEndDate)  {
    return

}
return null;
    }
```

I need to check the validity of the dates in each from the date and to date pair. That is if the to date is smaller than from date error message should be displayed near the to date. I have added the code below. Thanks.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are doing string comparison instead of date comparison so first convert it to a date object using new Date() and then compare these date objects.

```
let startDate = '01/30/2018';  //date format is - mm/dd/yyyy
let endDate = '12/10/2017'; //date format is - mm/dd/yyyy

let newStartDate = new Date(startDate);
let newEndDate = new Date(endDate);
     
if (newStartDate.valueOf() > newEndDate.valueOf()) {
   return;
}
```

Comment: I did it what have to do next how do I validate it and show an error msg.

Comment: Which validation do you want to set and in which condition the error message should be shown?

Comment: i want to show error when end date is less than start date and validate it

Comment: I have already checked this condition.

if (newStartDate.valueOf() > newEndDate.valueOf()) {
    //Show your error message here 
}

Comment: Please tell me , what are you getting in object of test.bidProgramStartDate and test.bidProgrammeEndDate

Comment: can you connect with me